# why content_rowid must be integer in FTS?

Tags: sqlite

Why content_rowid must be integer in FTS?

And what if content_rowid be a not primary integer key?

I create a VIRTUAL TABLE and TRIGGER width content_rowid equal to a not primary integer key, it works, has there any hidden risk?

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (a, createTime INTEGER NOT NULL);
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE fts USING fts5(a, content=tbl, content_rowid=createTime);

CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS tbl_ai AFTER INSERT ON tbl
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO fts (rowid, a)
  VALUES (new.createTime, new.a);
 END;
```

Is there anywayt to set content_rowid to a text column？I have tried，throw error `dataType mismatch`

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (a, guid text NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE fts USING fts5(a, content=tbl, content_rowid=guid);

CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS tbl_ai AFTER INSERT ON tbl
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO fts (rowid, a)
  VALUES (new.guid, new.a);
 END;
```

Comment: if anyone's wondering the current state of things, in 3.40.1 I tried the second one, and all seemed well ;)

Comment: @Mattwmaster58 it still does not work. Did you try to actually insert a row into tbl ?

Comment: @YannColeu Yes. You can see an implementation in my project but it's quite a bit more complex than this minimum example. I generate the the trigger statements dynamically: https://github.com/Mattwmaster58/MacTrack

Answer (score -3):

Your virtual table explicitly references `tbl.createTime`, which is an integer. The resulting virtual column is of the same type, necessarily.

Comment: Is there anywayt to set content_rowid to a text column？I have tried，throw error ```dataType mismatch```

Comment: I adressed that explicitly in my answer.

Comment: "Your virtual table explicitly references tbl.createTime". Yes, the *first* example does, the *second* one, which is the one that is the focus of the question, doesn't, it references `guid`.